# Stop player walking stright through the fence?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Newbie...How can I stop my player from walking straight through the fence? I need to keep the navmesh in place, as longer-term want him to be able to destroy part of the fence and walk through.. https://www.loom.com/share/693b10bf6c064715a99232be31e11b8b

I have a box collider on the fence.
Player has a ridgebody...

I saw this post, but does not resolve [Unity3D Player walking through and on the Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70315094/unity3d-player-walking-through-and-on-the-stone)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `Nav Mesh Obstacle` component to the fence and check the `Carve`. In this case, the fence deviates from the path and your character moves along it. The `carve` option will force fence to updated in real time, and solves the second problem but If you want to create a gap between the fence, you have to divide the fence into two semi part fences through specific script and give each of them `Nav Mesh obstacles` according to the same parameters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: very good answer, but the little fellow still goes straight through the fence :-(

Comment: Can you show the player movement code? If you have used navigation, it should not be so difficult.

Comment: I can, I actually have the code in GitHub if thats better?

Comment: Of course, the GitHub link is very good if you have the code there.

Comment: Great, https://github.com/dano007/My-project-24-

Comment: is this what you needed?

Comment: @Dano007 I downloaded the project and opened it with Unity 2019.4f, but the console shows 160 errors. Please guide which scene to open and in which folder has the character movement code?